# How to apply lstm in speech emotion feature

Tags: python, speech-recognition, lstm

I'd like to apply lstm in my speech emotion datasets (dataset of features in numeric values with one column of targets). 
I've done split_train_test. Do I need some other transformation to do in the data set before the model?
I ask this question because when I compile and fit the model I've got one error in the last dense layer.

> Error when checking model target: expected activation_2 to have shape (8,) but got array with shape (1,).

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After my internship I learn how to fix out this error and where to look.

Here's what you have to take care.

**Unexpected error input form**
If the reported layer is the first it is a cause of the input data for the train of a model as a same shape for a create your model.

If this is the **last layer that bug** then it is the labels that are well coded
Either you put a sigmoid but the labels are not binary either you put softmax and the labels are in one-hot format [0,1,0]: example 3 classes, this element is of class 2. So, the labels are badly encoded or you are deceived in the function (sigmoid / softmax) of your output layer.
Hope this help